# How to add all emails from a domain to a label in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

Hope I am not duplicating a thread, I searched but did not find this particular question.

In Gmail, I know how to have labels added to all emails from a *specific* sender, but how do I set it up such that anyone emailing from that domain automatically gets the label? I work for an agency where there are multiple contacts, and sometimes new people e-mail me from that company, and I'd like it all go to one place.

Thank you!

Comment: This is certainly a duplicate.  However the answer before it is closed for lack of research ;-)  is ``from:domain`` e.g. ``from:gmail.com``